# Htaccess redirect adds filepath to url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my .html links to .php. The actual files have been renamed to php as well so my current .html links don't work. I tried this rewrite first which works as in it loads the page but doesn't change the url.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

But when I change the rewrite to redirect, it no longer works. It adds the file path to the url.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R=302]
```

For instance: *www.domain.com/page.html* redirects to *www.domain.com/home/username/public_html/page.php*

I've read many similar questions and tried their solutions but I haven't been able to solve the problem.

Comment: If you have other rules, you can try to put yours first.

Comment: This is the only rule in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add slash before destination and rewritebase maybe it work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Rewrite file.html to file.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [L]
```

301 Redirect to file.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [R=301,L]
```